# Why don't cmake CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH override my root filesystem when cross-compiling?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling

I have successfully cross-compiled a `Poco` library for ARM on Ubuntu/x86_64. Now I'm cross-compiling a program that uses `Poco` with `cmake`.

I've installed Poco headers & includes on my target filesystem into `$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/local/include`.

I also have `Poco` development libraries on my host filesystem, and it gets in the way.

In my program's `CMakeLists.txt`, I'm looking for Poco like

```
find_path(POCO_INCLUDE_PATH "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h" "../include")
MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Poco: " ${POCO_INCLUDE_PATH-NOTFOUND} ":" ${POCO_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

I keep getting

```
Poco: :/usr/include
```

**Looks like my host's Poco in /usr/include takes precedence over one installed into $(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem, while /usr/local should not have been searched at all**.

I'm running `cmake` with a command:

```
. $(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/environment-setup \
    && mkdir -p $(BANANA_DIR) \
    && cd $(BANANA_DIR) \
    && CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/local \
        CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem \
        CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem:$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/include:$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/local/include \
        CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/lib:$(SDK_INSTALL_DIR)/filesystem/usr/local/lib \
        cmake ..
```

Both `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and `CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH` should have took precedence, but this didn't happen.

**edit:** I'm running my host's `cmake`. In a perfect world, this should not matter, but I think it's one of my problems. There's no `cmake` in the cross-compiling toolchain.

How do I get my `find_path()` to include the right `Poco`? Adding an explicit path to CMakeLists.txt is a bad option, as I need to compile the program on different platforms.

Comment: Is there any particular reason, why you are cross-compiling Poco manually? Have you looked at such projects as [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)?

Comment: Try find_path(... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)  http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:find_path

Comment: There is: we have some vendor-specific code that I doubt will smoothly compile of buildroot. And we have about hundred other packages compiled and pre-installed as binaries, including kernel and its modules. Thanks for advice though.

Comment: @Sergey, Thanks for pointing me to that piece of documentation :) `NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH` worked. Now I need to make it work on default paths too to make it a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem part was a complicated setup - I am using the host's `cmake` when cross-compiling.

Another part is a still unclear [find_path()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_path.html) behavior, where no combination of:

- `NO_something` flags in `find_path()`
- and `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`, and even `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH` variables

worked.

I ended up using an own `FindPoco.cmake` ([this one](http://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/resource_files/FindPoco.cmake) worked instantly) with a build command:

```
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=$(EXEC_DIR):$(EXEC_DIR)/usr/include:$(EXEC_DIR)/usr/local/include \
    CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$(EXEC_DIR):$(EXEC_DIR)/usr/lib:$(EXEC_DIR)/usr/local/lib \
    POCO_ROOT=$(POCO_DIR) \
    cmake -DPoco_DIR=$(POCO_DIR)/cmake .. \
&& make VERBOSE=1
```

My CMakeLists.txt now only mentions Poco like this:

```
find_package(Poco REQUIRED)
find_library(POCO_FOUNDATION PocoFoundation ${Poco_LIBRARY_DIRS} REQUIRED)
find_library(POCO_NET PocoNet ${Poco_LIBRARY_DIRS} REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Poco_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(detect ${POCO_FOUNDATION} ${POCO_NET})
```

and it could be even shorter.

Comment: I'm open to accept a better explanation of `find_path()` as an answer.